# Multiplying elements in two different lists then summing up the nested loop

Tags: python, nested-lists

So I have two sets of nested lists:

```py
l = [[3,4,4],[1,2,1]]
w = [[2,4,1],[3,1,3]]
```

I want look at each nested list, multiply the two values of l and w (for example in first nested loop 3*2) then add them all up to make sure each nested list has a total area of less than 40. In the case of the first pair of lists `3*2 + 4*4 + 4*1 + 1*3 + 2*1 + 1*3` is 34 which is less than 40.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: How do you arrive at a total of 40?  I got 34.  (3*2 + 4*4 + 4*1 + 1*3 + 2*1 + 1*3)

Comment: I meant as long as the sum is less than 40!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this should work just fine:

```
summ = 0
for l_sub_list,w_sub_list in zip(l,w): #zip will join each element of l with w #element on the same index.
    for l_sub_val,w_sub_val in zip(l_sub_list,w_sub_list):
        print(f"{l_sub_val} * {w_sub_val}")
        summ += l_sub_val*w_sub_val

print(summ)
```

You can also go for shorter solution:

```
flat_l = [x for sublist in l for x in sublist] #Creating flat list, with no sub lists.
flat_w = [x for sublist in w for x in sublist]
result = sum([l_number * w_number for l_number,w_number in zip(flat_l,flat_w)])  #Using comprehensive lists, to multiply elements from flat_l list by flat_w list elmeents. Then, summing it with sum function/

print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> l = [[3,4,4],[1,2,1]]; w = [[2,4,1],[3,1,3]]
>>> list(zip(l,w))
[([3, 4, 4], [2, 4, 1]), ([1, 2, 1], [3, 1, 3])]
>>> for a,b in zip(l,w):
...   s = sum(c*d for c,d in zip(a,b))
...   print(s)
...
26
8
>>>
```